# Unsupported consistency level: LOCAL_QUORUM. Supported consistency levels for Search are: ONE, LOCAL_ONE

Tags: java, database, cassandra, cqlsh, dse

I faced an issue when using cqlsh to query on dse 6.7.

```
Invalid Request: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unsupported consistency level: LOCAL_QUORUM. Supported consistency levels for Search are: ONE, LOCAL_ONE".
```

My query is very simple is:

Query :

```
select * from esc shipment . shipment search where shipper id like '1334';
```

I spent a lot of time to google but I did not find any use case same same my case.

Could anyone tell me the main reason and how to fix this issue.
I'm a very beginner.

Comment: Please post info about your cluster and output of `desc shipment` command (describe of your keyspace).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is following - you're running your query with `LIKE` operator on the table that has DSE Search enabled.  Because CQL doesn't have `LIKE` operator, this query is offloaded to the DSE Search that is able to answer queries only with consistency level `ONE` or `LOCAL_ONE` (as it's pointed in the error - it's a known limitation of DSE Search).

You need to change consistency level with the cqlsh command [CONSISTENCY](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshConsistency.html), lie this:

```
CONSISTENCY LOCAL_ONE
```

and then execute the query again.

Comment: For more details, I face the same problem with solr query,
{"q": "shipper_id: 1334"} with LOCAL_QUORUM consistency level.
it returns the same error message.
Is it the solr query perform the same shipper id like '1334' ?
And could you give me any solution to use LOCAL_QUORUM with the search query in this case?

Comment: you can't use DSE Search queries with something not like ONE or LOCAL_ONE... Other consistency levels will be supported only in SAI available in 6.8

Comment: Thank you so much, Seem this tech stack not very popular. I can not find out the same the issue on google.

Comment: see https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/siQuerySyntax.html#Filteringrestrictionsandbestpractices